# secureChannel.unwrap function return 6982(Security status not satisfied)

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I want using secure messaging in my applet by org.globalplatform package. I have a library in C# which implements some of globalplatform commands. I can open secure channel to card in CLR, MAC and ENC mode and i can load and install applet on card in mentioned mode.
Also i open secure channel in my applet successfuly and external authentication response 9000. like this:

```
case INS_INIT_UPDATE:
case INS_External_AUTHENTICATION:
      SDInstruction(apdu);
      break;
```

and

```
private void SDInstruction(APDU apdu) 
    {
        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte cla = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA];
        byte ins = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

    apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        if(ins == INS_INIT_UPDATE)
            secureChannel = GPSystem.getSecureChannel();

        short len = secureChannel.processSecurity(apdu);

        apdu.setOutgoing();
    apdu.setOutgoingLength(len);
        apdu.sendBytes(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short) len);        
    }
```

but when i want unwrap command apdu "which wraped by global platform c# library" in my applet , cardManager return 6982(Security Status not satisfid).unwraping code:

```
byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
if (secureChannel.getSecurityLevel() < (SecureChannel.AUTHENTICATED))
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED);

        short len = secureChannel.unwrap(buf, (short) 0, (short) buf.length);
```

trace of secure channel apdu:

```
Command APDU >> Class=00 Ins=A4 P1=04 P2=00 P3=09 Data=A00000030800001000
Response APDU << SW=611A
Command APDU >> Class=00 Ins=C0 P1=00 P2=00 P3=1A 
Response APDU << SW=9000 Data=61174F06000010000100790D4F0BA00000030800001000010009
Command APDU >> Class=80 Ins=50 P1=00 P2=00 P3=08 Data=0101010101010101
Response APDU << SW=611C
Command APDU >> Class=00 Ins=C0 P1=00 P2=00 P3=1C 
Response APDU << SW=9000 Data=4D0022840106A783224FFF01AF258B0267752E248D07854961DA9851
Command APDU >> Class=84 Ins=82 P1=01 P2=00 P3=10 Data=F6E5BC84DE83E5242E8B6C9CA0ECB741
Response APDU << SW=9000
Command APDU >> Class=04 Ins=20 P1=00 P2=80 P3=0E Data=3131313131315F34DCF6BE7EDD3A
Response APDU << SW=6982
Wrapping apdu command faild.
```

Anyone can help me?
Thank you very much,

Mohsen.

Comment: Adding APDU commands trace to your question is useful. You can also replace `ISO7816.SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED` with `(short) secureChannel.getSecurityLevel()` in the `if(...)` block to check its value. :)

Comment: hi abraham,(short) secureChannel.getSecurityLevel() return 0x81

Comment: Hi dear Mohsen. You have been restricted CLA values to `CLA_GP` or `0x84` in the 4th line of `SDInstruction` method and your last APDU command's CLA is `0x04`. Right? Is there similar restriction for this command in your applet?

Comment: thanks for reply. sorry in last version of code this block are deleted.

Comment: Based on GlobalPlatform Specificication, the `unwrap()` method throws `CLA_NOT_SUPPORT` only. So you receive this status word from somewhere else in your applet. Is it possible to share whole the applet source with us?

Comment: unwrap method decrypt apdu command and check MAC. if only MAC apply to Security level in external authentication command, unwrap method only check  MAC on command apdu. if MAC doesn't verify it throws 6982 (security status not satisfied).

Comment: Im sure the  short len = secureChannel.unwrap(buf, (short) 0, (short) buf.length); return 6982.

Comment: I see you handle the `INS_External_AUTHENTICATION` instruction in the first block of code but not in the second. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your unwrapping command specifies a wrong length.
try:

```
short len = secureChannel.unwrap(buf, (short) 0, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + apdu.getIncomingLength()));
```